# How to change namespace if I have application with abc namespace?

Tags: c#-4.0

Suppose I have namespace abc and I want to change it with def.xyz Then is there any way other than edit each and every file in my application and make changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need to change the namespace in every file if what you want is to change the namespace to a different one. This can be done using global search and replace (supported by Visual Studio).

If all you want to do is refer to this namespace by a different name, you do **not**, however need to refer to it as `abc` in other code, as you can [alias a namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d.aspx):

```
using def.xyz = abc;
```

Comment: +1 for [alias a namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use any commercial tools, you will have to do it by hand. A search-replace could help but you need to be careful.

[Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Refactorings__Adjust_Namespaces.html) is a tool that can help you with renaming namespaces.